# Definition of Numerical Trivial Invertible Sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, complex-geometry

I am reading Ravi Vakil's book, Foundations of Algebraic Geometry and in section 18.4.9, the definition of numberically trivial invertible sheaf is,

Suppose $X$ is a proper $k-$ variety, and $\mathcal{L}$ is an invertible sheaf on $X$. If $i:C \hookrightarrow X$ is a one-dimensional closed subscheme of X, define the degree of $\mathcal{L}$ on $C$ to by 
\begin{equation}
\text{deg}_C~\mathcal{L}:=\text{deg}_C~i^*\mathcal{L}
\end{equation} 
If $\text{deg}_C \mathcal{L}=0$ for all $C$, we say $\mathcal{L}$ is numerically trivial.

In the definition, $C$ is only a one-dimensional closed sub-scheme, but I kind of feel there should be some restrictions on $C$, like it should be reduced or even regular projective over $k$, is it right? What is the corresponding definition in the classical complex geometry case?

Comment: A proper curve is projective, this is in Hartshorne and I guess it is in Vakil's notes, too.

Comment: @MooS, thank you. I just realize that since $i:C \rightarrow X$ is a closed embedding, which is proper. $X \rightarrow Spec k$ is also proper, so $C \rightarrow Spec k$ is proper and so it is projective.

Comment: "numerically" means it is defined by intersection theory.

Comment: "What is the corresponding definition in the classical complex geometry case?" It is exactly the same.